# Matrix similar to its square

Tags: matrices, similar-matrices

I am trying to find the matrices $ M \in M_n (\mathbb{R})$ such that $M$ is similar to $M^2$.

I tried to use the fact that if these matrices are similar, then they have the same eigenvalues, but I could not really get anywhere with this.

I would be grateful if you could at least give me a hint.
Thank you.

Comment: Examples are $M=I$ or any other [idempotent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20an%20idempotent,idempotent%20elements%20of%20matrix%20rings.) that satisfy $M^2=M$. Are you looking for an exhaustive characterization?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough but yes, I would like to find all of these matrices if that is possible.

Comment: Any permutation matrix corresponding to a cyclic permutation of odd order will have this property. More generally, I suspect that any matrix satisfying $M^n = I$ for some odd $n$ will have this property

Comment: @JackEight Could you give us some context? Where did you encounter this problem, or what inspired you to ask it? Do we have any reason to suspect that this question has a "nice" answer (for instance, is this a problem from a textbook)?

Comment: Also any (not necessarily diagonalizable) matrix $M$ whose only eigenvalue is $1$ will have this property

Comment: Thank you, I will be thinking about this. As for the context, this problem comes from a French qualification examination (an oral test, actually)

Comment: @JackEight I think the nicest description we could come up with is as follows: $M$ has this property if and only if the eigenvalue $0$ is non-defective and for each non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$, the Jordan form of $M$ has the same blocks for $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Uh, you are right. I was mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to understand this

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $A\sim A^k$, we only need to prove that $J\sim J^k$,where J denotes any Jordan block of the Jordan canonical form of A.

Also,$J=\lambda I+J_0$,the characteristic polynomial of $J$ is $(\lambda-a)^{r_i}$.Through discussion with determinant factors and minimal polynomial,we know that the Jordan canonical form of $J_{r_i}(\lambda_i)^m$ is $J_{r_i}(\lambda_i^m)$,so we need nonzero eigenvalues to be $1$(when $k =2$).

Plus, when we look the Jordan canonical form of $J_{r_i}(0)^m$, we can prove that the result should be $diag${ ${J_{q}(0)}$ , ${J_{q}(0)}$,$\cdots$}
So the answer is obvious.

Comment: So all the eigenvalues should be $1$, i.e. the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(\lambda -1)^n$

Comment: If you got trouble with the proof, just @ me. The proof of the last paragraph is somewhat complicated.

Comment: As I state in the comments on the question, it is possible that $A$ is similar to $A^2$, but $A$ has an eigenvalue not equal to $1$. As an example, consider $$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}.$$

Comment: Sorry,I missed one thing, considering the permutation, if the Jordan form of $A$ is the same as one of $A^k$, Then we can get the answer. Through my answer you can get the Jordan form of $A^k$.  Some of my claims are wrong too.Hope the OP will get the point himself. When I get the time,I'll rewrite it.