# Determine all matrices $A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ is similar to $A^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine all matrices $A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ is similar to $A^2$.

I know that for the matrix the solution belongs the Jordan shape of $A$ must equal the Jordan shape of $A^2$. How can I generalize this result?

I know these two matrices are solutions.

\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
and
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Can you help me?

Comment: The second matrix is not a solution

Comment: See the comments on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4144713/81360)

Comment: To copy my comment from there: I think the nicest description we could come up with is that $A$ has this property if and only if the eigenvalue 0 is non-defective and for each non-zero eigenvalue , the Jordan form of $A$ has the same blocks for $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$.

Comment: Do my comments answer your question to your satisfaction? If not, please explain what you feel would be necessary for a complete answer